# How to change permissions of multiple files found with find command?

Tags: shell, permissions, find

I have a directory with numerous files. Part of the files have the `755` permissions and the other part have `644` permissions. I'd like to convert the files with `755` permissions to `644`. I have tried the following line by running it from the directory itself:

```
find . -perm 755 -exec chmod 644 {}\;
```

However as a result, the permission changed only for the directory itself and after changing it back I found out that the files permissions remained unchanged. Do I miss something?

Comment: Your command removes the executable bit from the directory, making it impossible to chdir to it and look at the files it contains. That's why the command doesn't seem to be working. Try `find ./ -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;` instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I've found the problem. It seems that there must be a **mandatory space** between the `{}` and `\;`, so the command will look like this:

```
find . -perm 755 -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Rather than:

```
find . -perm 755 -exec chmod 644 {}\;
```

Also the issue with changing the directory permissions can be solved by adding a `-type f` flag, so it'll look as follows:

```
find . -type f -perm 755 -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: You could use `+` instead of `\;` to reduce the number of subprocesses created.

Comment: `-type d` will find directories. `-type f` will find files.